# How can I get textbox value into array and convert into integer in java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I need to get ***textbox*** value into ***array*** and convert them into **integer**.

I'm not sure whether should I **1st convert and get into array** or **get into array and after convert**.

Please explain with relevant examples
I've already tied out this code segment. But its wrong according to my knowledge.

```
           String data [] = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
```

Comment: Give an example of what the text looks like since it appears you are trying to convert a single textual integer into an array of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] stringValues = jTextField1.getText().split("[,]");
int[] numArray= new int[stringValues.length];

    for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
        numArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringValues[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an single inter to a string array so it will not work.
Because two types are incompatible.

Either you must have an integer array or you can have string array and use string value of the textfield.

e.g.

```
 String []stringData  = {jTextField1.getText()};
```

or

```
 int [] = {Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())};
```

But since you are using just single value it is better to use an variable rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "34,56,78,32,45";
String[] parts = str.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) 
{  
    int no=Interger.parse(parts[i]);
    //Do your stuff here
}
```